# hplip 3.16.2: no installed HP device found (while CUPS finds it)

Tags: cups, printer, scanner, sane, hplip

I was investigating further an issue already reported [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273681/xsane-states-that-no-devices-are-available-any-longer). The problem is: after having upgraded the **hplip** driver to **3.16.2**, the scanner in my all-in-one printer **HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M277dw** does not work any longer (while the printer does). Today I found other oddities that seem specific to **hplip** rather than to **sane**, whereby this other post.

I use **Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS**. In all that follows the device is connected and powered-on. The hplip page for that device is [here](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/color_laserjet/hp_color_laserjet_mfp_m277dw.html).

## Evidences

**a.** Moving on from the [**sane** community page on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/sane), I followed the suggestion to run `sudo hp-setup`. The answer is

`warning: CUPSEXT could not be loaded. Please check HPLIP installation.`

**b.** If run `hp-doctor`, the welcome message is

`error: This distro (i.e ubuntu  14.04) is either deprecated or not yet supported.`

This sounds utterly odd to me, because the previous hplip did not dare to complain this far of the very same distro. The complete output of hp-doctor is available [from here on Paste Ubuntu](http://paste.ubuntu.com/18910761/).

**c.** Ever more puzzling, if I open the HP device manager, I am presented with the window

[image]

which seems a false statement to me, since the device works as a printer at the very least. If I click on `Setup device...` I get again the same dialogue window. And **CUPS** on localhost:631 indeed confirms that the printer is there ready to be found, nice and idle.

## Questions

Is there a way to have the commands `hp-setup` and `hp-doctor` run smoothly so that I can fix the scanner issue down the line?

If not, how do I downgrade the hplip driver to the previous stable version? Installing 3.16.2 has led to more havoc than joy.

Comment: To answer the question in the title, that depends on the driver and/or the interface that's being used by the printer.  As the Note states, only hp prefixes are shown in that hp device manager.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem with Ubuntu version 14.04: Upgrade to 16.04  http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/

Comment: This is a good recommendation, but maybe not an Answer...

Comment: @jasonryan & sam: I dont understand your reply. XavierStuvw is running and old Ubuntu 14.04. Please explain why it is a bad suggestion to upgrade to 16.04.

Comment: @Jeff where is the "recommendation" button?

Comment: "Add a comment" under the question

Comment: I am a bit confused by the answer and comments. Anyhow my preference, for the time being, goes to downgrading hplip rather than upgrading Ubuntu. Thinking abstractly, I see no sound point why a driver should get installed in a OS it is incompatible with. And, if memory serves well, I upgraded hplip following some notification that I trusted to be fool-proof.